# scadabr describe how create new component

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp-tags, scadalts

How implement own component in scadabr?

For example:

1. clock, http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/css3analogclock.shtml
2. thermometer, http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-goal-thermometer/6358236

etc

With own javascript lib.

With editor properties in edit view.

With editor properties in viewer view.

Comment: Now, based on ScadaBR it created project Scada-LTS.